# How to use map with two lists?

Tags: sml

In SML, how can you use a map function that takes two lists and returns a list of each element in one list multiplied with its corresponding element in the other list?

I tried

```
fun mult_list v1 v2 = map (fn (x, y) => x * y) (v1, v2);
```

but it's not working...

Answer (score 3):

You want [`ListPair.map`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html#SIG%3aLIST_PAIR.map%3aVAL):

```
fun mult_list v1 v2 = ListPair.map (fn (x, y) => x * y) (v1, v2)
```

which, btw, can be abbreviated to

```
fun mult_list v1 v2 = ListPair.map op* (v1, v2)
```

You can also use [`ListPair.mapEq`](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html#SIG%3aLIST_PAIR.map%3aVAL) instead, if you want to force an exception when the lists are not of the same length.